# ¿Existe un verbo para indicar que se está escuchando una conversación ajena?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Recuerdo que en mi casa se usaba la expresión "parar oreja" para indicar que se estaba escuchando una conversación ajena. En el DLE se encuentra una expresión un tanto similar

> **[parar la oreja](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RAXzs7l)**:
> *1. loc. verb. coloq. Am. Mer., Guat., Méx. y R. Dom*. aguzar las orejas (‖ prestar atención).

Sin embargo, esta expresión no es exactamente la misma que aquella que menciono al comienzo, pues no tiene la connotación de estar escuchando una conversación ajena. No sabría decir si la expresión que yo conozco y el significado que tiene es propio de Colombia o es un regionalismo.

Como sea, mi duda es si existe un verbo, no una expresión, que indique que se escucha algo sin ser el receptor intencionado del mensaje.

**Edit**: Encontré que en inglés existe el verbo que busco (definición en Google translator):

> **overhear**
>
> hear (someone or something) without meaning to or without the knowledge of the speaker.
>
> "I couldn't help overhearing your conversation"

Sin embargo, la traducción a español que encontré de "overhear" es "escuchar", con lo que creo que se pierde parte del significado.

Comment: En inglés, aparte del "overhear" que mencionas en la pregunta, también existe "eavesdrop", que significa "secretly listen to a conversation."

Comment: En España diríamos *pegar la oreja* con un significado similar. Lo mismo sirve para, simplemente, poner atención, como para escuchar disimuladamente lo que dicen otros.

Comment: Overhear: *oír de pasada, oír de casualidad*.

Answer (score 4):

En España podrías usar [**cotillear**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=B8zW99j) en su segunda acepción. Por ejemplo:

> Ayer estuve hablando con Pepe y quise contarle lo de Marisa, pero al final no lo hice porque me di cuenta de que Jorge nos estaba cotilleando.

Y bueno, obviamente también tendrías verbos como [**espiar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GaDmLmS%7CGaF6J9p).

Answer (score 3):

Como verbo está [**orejear**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RAZg4Uq) que, según en DLE, es

> 3. tr. *El Salv. y Nic.* **Escuchar indiscretamente asuntos ajenos.**

aunque el Diccionario de americanismos amplía el área en el que se usa a **Mx, ES, Ni, CR, RD, Bo:S.**

Por otro lado, como sustantivos tienes [**escucha**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GLXwomr):

> 2. f. Acción y efecto de espiar una comunicación privada.

y como adjetivos, [**escuchaño**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GLkUyH4):

> 1. adj. desus. Que escucha indiscretamente.

o [**escuchón**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GLnBeQl):

> 1. adj. despect. Que escucha con curiosidad indiscreta lo que otros hablan, o lo que no debe. U. t. c. s.

Answer (score 3):

Cosas que voy encontrando en el diccionario:

- ***[Orejear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RAZg4Uq)***: escuchar indiscretamente asuntos ajenos. Usada en El Salvador y Nicaragua.
- ***[Husmear](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Kr9ujpj)***: indagar algo con arte y disimulo. *Indagar* a su vez es "intentar averiguar algo discurriendo o con preguntas". Luego quien husmea está intentando averiguar algo con disimulo, en lo que podría encajar el hecho de estar oyendo una conversación ajena sin que se den cuenta.

Sobre el verbo *overhear* en inglés, yo diría que según la intención del que oye la conversación se puede traducir como "oír sin querer" o "sin pretenderlo":

> Perdonadme, sin querer he oído lo que decíais.

Usar *oír* en vez de *escuchar* reforzaría la idea de que la acción no se pretendía. Si la acción sí se pretendía y se ha hecho sin conocimiento de los hablantes, se podría decir *escuchar [a escondidas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GHdf2O2)*:

> Ten cuidado, alguien podría estar escuchando a escondidas lo que decimos.

Frase que también se puede expresar como:

> Cuidado, las paredes oyen.

Answer (score 3):

Por estos lugares de México usamos el "[**metiche**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=P78VvU3)" y verbos generados de éste, como **matichear, meticheando, etc.**

Ejemplos:

> **No seas metiche / No andes de metiche**
>
> > *significado no estés metiéndote / fisgoneando / husmeando en los asuntos de los demás*
>
> **Que metiche eres**
>
> > eres muy entrometido en los asuntos de otros
>
> **Cuidado, Juanito anda / esta de metiche/ Cuidado, Juanito esta meticheando**
>
> > Cuidado, Juanito esta de fisgón.

Metiche y chismoso pueden ser muy parecidos, pero la diferencia es que metiche es el que obtiene la informacion y el chismoso es el que la divulga.

Así que un metiche puede ser un tipo de sinónimo de "espía" pero no tan formal, es alguien que busca información de los demás y puede ser escuchando, viendo, investigando, etc.

El problema con *overheard* es que metiche implica que lo hiciste intencionalmente, mientras que *overheard* tiene una conotacion de que fue escuchado por accidente.

Para que tenga esa connotación, tendríamos que decir **"Alcancé a oír / escuchar"**, de lo cual no creo que exista una palabra en específico en el español para expresar eso.

Comment: Claro que sí. En Chile también se usa mucho.

Comment: De acuerdo; Mike, tu respuesta quedaría mejor con un ejemplo que muestre cómo usar *metiche* en una frase. // Qué piensas, fisgonear se puede usar también en el contexto de lo que se oye?

Answer (score 2):

También sirve, al menos en España:

> [**marujear**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OVx7nRj)
>
> 1. *intr. despect. coloq. Esp.* Hacer lo que se considera propio de marujas o de marujos.

básicamente porque
el término **maruja** se suele utilizar para designar una persona cotilla y chismosa. Adjunto su definición.

> [**maruja**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OW2nUGj)
>
> 1. *f. despect. coloq. Esp.* Mujer que se dedica solo a las tareas domésticas y a la que suele asociarse a ciertos tópicos como el
>    chismorreo, la dependencia excesiva de la televisión, etc. U. t. c.
>    adj.
> 2. *m. irón. coloq. Esp.* Hombre que actúa como una maruja (‖ mujer que se dedica solo a las tareas del hogar). U. t. c. adj.
> 3. *m. y f. despect. coloq. Esp.* Persona chismosa. U. m. c. adj.
> 4. *adj. despect. coloq. Esp.* Propio o característico de las marujas o de los marujos.

Comment: ¡Buena! Añadí por cierto enlace a las entradas que referencias.

Comment: ¡Te lo agradezco!